# How do I delete all repeated letters?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need a command that erases all the letters that repeat

Input:

```
this is a message
```

Output:

```
this a meg
```

some commands that I tried but did not work

```
echo testsss |sed 's/([a-zA-Z])\1+/\1/g'

echo testsss |tr -s 'a-z'
```

Comment: Repeat only in a line but not the entire file? Only alphabets (not numbers, punctuation, spaces)?

Comment: can not repeat just it

Comment: letters, numbers, scores can not repeat

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to distinguish space from the other character, you could use `awk`:

```
awk -v FS= '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s",($i in a)?"":$i;a[$i]}; printf "\n"}' <<< 'this is a message'
this ameg
```

The field separator `FS` is set to nothing in order to capture each single character composing the string.

The array `a` is filled with each character. If this character is not part of the array, it is printed, otherwise skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very quick approach with Python's Ordered Dictionary. Probably could be done better, but that's the first thing of the top of my head that suits your requirement of basically having `uniq` for characters in a string, and in accordance with the example in question - preserving order of characters.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

char_map = OrderedDict()
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    chars = list(arg)
    for c in chars:
        char_map[c] = True
    for uniq_char in char_map.keys():
        print(uniq_char)
```

Works as so:

```
$ ./uniqc.py 'this is a message'
t
h
i
s

a
m
e
g
```

Note it also works on spaces.

Comment: would it not be possible to use the sed or tr commands?

Comment: @Seehrum If the order doesn't matter, `awk` can be used.  `tr` doesn't have capability for that, and `sed` probably would be extremely complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to treat space as a character to be de-duplicated (which you seem to be, based on the accepted answer) then one option is to use the `distinct` function from Perl's `List::MoreUtils`:

```
echo 'this is a message' | 
  perl -MList::MoreUtils=distinct -F'' -lpe '$_ = join "", distinct @F'
this ameg
```